# grep for argument of a latex command

Tags: grep, latex

I'm trying to sort out some broken references in a latex file. They are commands such as `\cref{ps.1.1}`. I would like to grep my file and get only the argument of the command as output, in this case `ps.1.1`. `grep -Po \\\\cref{.*?} my.tex` gives me only the command, not the rest of the line, but I'd like to also get rid of the `\cref{` and `}` in the output, so that I could iterate over them.

Comment: input and expected output??

Comment: Don't use `grep` use `awk`.

Comment: (1) Precisely what output do you want?  (What does "_not the rest of the line_" mean -- do you want the rest?)  Just contents of `{}`? The line with that but without the command itself?  The whole file with these commands removed / replaced-by-other?  There are many things you may want, please specify.  (2) What tool do you require, if any?  Strictly one-liner or a script?   Note that `grep`'s main job is to give you whole lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a Perl one-liner, printing out only the matches, including multiple ones on the same line. It puts out a line per match, even for those on the same line, prepended with their line numbers.

```
perl -nle 'print "$.: $1" while(/\\cref\{(.*?)\}/g)' file.tex
```

This may need to and can be modified, depending on the exact output you want.

For example, to print just once for multiple matches on the same line, drop the `/g` modifier (remove `g` after the regex). To match multiple patterns, add them to the regex (separated by `|` and grouped by `()`) and add `$2`, `$3` (...) to `print`. To see the whole line, change `$1` to `$_`. Etc.

A simple script would offer far more flexiblity and processing opportunities.

Comment: `perl -nle 'print "$1" while(/\\cref\{(.*?)\}/g)' file.tex` was what I was thinking of.